# Throwing Rest Exceptions in my Application Services vs adding extra logic to my controller to determine if I need to reply with a 404

Tags: c#, restful-architecture, onion-architecture

Im struggling with two ways to return a HttpStatusCode.NotFound (and other Http Status Codes).

1.) My app service will throw a `RestException(HttpStatusCode code)` which is caught by Middleware and then a proper response is sent back and the response code is set. For example, if I have `[Httpget]GetEmployeeById(int Id)` and Id is not a real Employee Id, respond with 404.

2.) In my controller, the Application Service call to `GetByEmployee()` might return null, if so I `return NotFound()` which does the same as the middleware. But instead, this is done in the controller and the Application Service remains unaware of http status codes.

**RestException Pros:**

- Thinner controllers.
- Less complicated code. If I have an action called `PutEmployee(Employee employeeToUpdate)` I no longer need to write extra logic to fetch first to determine if it exists, pass around tracked entities, etc. The Application Service handles all of it.

**Returning Codes in Controller Pros:**

- Since I am using ActionResult, and I either return an `Employee` or `NotFound()` I dont need a `[ProducesResponseType(typeof(FluentValidationDataTableFieldError), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest))]` because this can be inferred.
- Http/API/Rest stuff stays where it belongs, in the controller.

Essentially, its the difference between the following snippets:

```cs
[HttpPost("", Name = EmployeeControllerRoute.PostEmployee)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(EmployeeCreateUpdateJsonModel), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(SpecialErrorViewModel), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public async Task<EmployeePageJsonViewModel> Post([FromBody]EmployeeCreateUpdateJsonModel employeeToAdd)
    => await _employeeService.AddAsync(employeeToAdd); // AddAsync throws `RestException(HttpStatusCode code)` if `employeeToAdd.Id` does not pull up a real item.
```

### VS

```cs
[HttpGet("{productIds}", Name = ProductControllerRoute.GetProducts)]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<ProductViewModel>>> Get(EntityIdList productIds)
{
    var products = await _productService.GetMultipleByIdAsync(productIds);

    if(products.Count != productIds.Count)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return products;
}
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Is it bad to mix these approaches?